# Sound libraries for ruby

Tags: ruby, audio

I'm looking for a ruby library that would let me read/write .wav (or another sound format, preferably loseless) files, and operate on waveform.

Answer (score 2):

The wavefile gem is quite straightforward.

https://github.com/jstrait/wavefile